# How to use VBA to open a file in a new window?

Tags: vba, shell, command-line-arguments, osisoft

I have a OSI PI Processbook file that I am using VBA on to open a new instance of PI Processbook. Basically I have a text element (Text35) on which I have a vba click event:

```
Private Sub Text35_Click(ByVal lvarX As Long, ByVal lvarY As Long)
    Dim filePathAndName As String
    Dim exeLocation As String
    Dim PID As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandle
filePathAndName = "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\TEST.PDI"
exeLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PIPC\Procbook\Procbook.exe"
PID = Shell("""" & exeLocation & """", vbNormalFocus)

'How can I use the above process id to open a PDI file??

Exit Sub
errHandle:
End Sub
```

Basically I want to open the `TEST.PDI` file on my desktop in **an entirely new copy** of PI Processbook. I've tried `pplication.Displays.Open(filePathAndName, True)` but this opens my `TEST.PDI` into the same instance of Processbook, not a new application instance like I want.

Is there some Shell command or command like switch argument I can use to both open a new instance of the .exe and open up a file at the same time? I, at least, have the process id of the new instance stored in the "PID" variable, so I am thinking this might help.

Comment: Answered my own question thanks to https://pisquare.osisoft.com/thread/11381   The solution was: `PID = Shell("""" & exeLocation & """ """ & filePathAndName & """", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because it's inappropriate. If you want to provide a solution, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that use. It's perfectly acceptable (and even encouraged) to answer your own question here. You can even mark it as the accepted answer (although you will not gain any reputation for doing so). See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more info.